# Prove $\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}\left\lfloor \frac{a \cdot j}{p} \right\rfloor = \frac{(a-1)(p-1)}{2}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number, and let $a$ be a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, such that $a \neq n p$ for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

$$\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}\left\lfloor \frac{a \cdot j}{p} \right\rfloor = \frac{(a-1)(p-1)}{2}$$

I have found that this is essentially a special case of [this formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#cite_note-15). I've attempted to follow the proof in Knuth's 'Concrete Mathematics' textbook, but found it challenging due to its approach, which involves listing and identifying patterns. Is there a simpler and more elegant proof available for this problem?